# Find the set of convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How the interval [a, b]:  $x \in [a,b]$ can be found for the next sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n}$$

The sence to check the next limit 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n} = f(x) \ne 0$$ 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
 1 , |x|<1 \\ 
-1 , |x|>1 \\ 
 \emptyset ,  x = \pm 1
\end{cases}$$
is to define a kind of convergence.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} {\sup_X { | \frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n}-f(x)|}} = s \ne 0$$
$$s = \begin{cases}
 2 , |x|<1 \\ 
-2 , |x|>1 \\ 
\emptyset ,  x =\pm 1
\end{cases}$$ 
It is the non-uniformly convergent series. Am I right?

How can I find the the convergent interval of x? Or prove, that interval = $\emptyset$?

Comment: if $|x| < 1$, $\frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n} \to 1 \ne 0$. if $|x| > 1$,  $\frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n} \to -1 \ne 0$. if $x = \pm 1$, $\frac{1+x^n}{1-x^n}$ is undefined for all even $n$. So the sums diverges/undefined everywhere.

Comment: Do I correct understand you? If there is a value, where lim $u_n(x)$ is undefined, it comes to the whole sum of series is undefined.

Comment: Yes. a single undefined value in a term of the sequence (for a given x) make your whole sum undefined (for that particular x).

Comment: OK. Only for particular x! (I meant for every x below). For other values x it must be proved separately. In this case the sum diverges for every x, because sum ~ $\pm n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Yes, you need to prove it for every other $x$. The behavior that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k z^k\text{ converges at } z = x \quad\implies\quad \text{ converges for every } |z| < |x|$$ only works for power series.

Answer (score 0):

You used L'Hospital rules to calculate the limit. You can only do this if you have a limit of type $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$. You don't have that if $|x|<1$.

So, for $|x|>1$, your calculation of the limit is correct. Because the limit is not $0$, this tells you a lot about the convergence of the sum.

For $|x|=1$, the sum is not even well defined. Now, analyze what happens if $|x|<1$. *hint*: calculating the same limit as before may still help.